# illegal initializer for 'java.lang.Integer'

Tags: java, android

I was following grid view example in https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview#example
to try gridView.

```
private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
        R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
        R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
        R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7,
        R.drawable.sample_0, R.drawable.sample_1,
        R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
        R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
        R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7,
        R.drawable.sample_0, R.drawable.sample_1,
        R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
        R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
        R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7
};
```

This part of code returns illegal initializer for 'java.lang.Integer' error. Android Studio also uses android.R.drawable unlike in this guide. Could it be outdated even though it says "*Last updated December 20, 2018.*"? If so, how to initialize it correctly?

Comment: Can you try to use ``private Integer[] mThumbIds = new Integer[] { ...``?

Comment: Is there a reason that you use `Integer` rather than `int`?